# Create first, login or signup later

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Using Rails 3.

In usual app, a form only appears if the user is logged in. Then in the controller, we will run another check on authentication before we save the new record.

However, I want to show the form to everyone regardless if he's logged in. When the visitor submits the form with attachment, etc., it will then check if the user is logged in. If he isn't, then redirect him to login/signup page, and when he's completed that, only then the new record is saved.

I understand this can be achieved with the `create` and `save`, but can someone elaborate more on how to achieve this in a clearer explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- User submits form
- Controller sees user is not logged in
- Controller persists submitted form to the database
- Controller sets cookie with id of new object
- Controller redirects to login
- User logs in
- Controller retrieves persisted form information from database
- Controller assigns object to user

Run a periodic job to clean old unclaimed form data.

Comment: The persists part is new to me. Any examples?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the view you'd show the form always without any kind of login check. The tricky part here is to save the data the user has sent before he's redirected to the login.

One solution would be to save the post data in a cookie and then redirect the user to the same page after the login, triggering the create again

On the controller you'd do exactly as you described:

```
class ThingController
  def create
    if user_logged_in?
      if cookie[:stuff]
        # create the stuff from cookie and remove it
      else
        # create the stuff
      end
    else
      # redirect him to login with a callback to this same place        
    end
  end
end
```